# Inbox folder in Outlook does not show new emails after updating folders

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, inbox

I am using Outlook 2010 with exchange email account on Windows 7 x64. I am able to receive new emails in webmail and mobile phone.

However, I cannot find new emails even if it shows that folder was last update at current time. I have tried to repaired/re-installed outlook but issue still persists.

Comment: Do you by chance have the `Today` group of emails collapsed?

Comment: Not at all. All Outlook folders are expanded.

Comment: When do the new messages show up? Or do they never?

Comment: If you do a search for an email, does it show? Is this a local exchange or a hosted exchange?

Comment: search does not show any email. This is local exchange.

Comment: @Twisty email shows few days later.

Comment: Try creating a new Outlook profile and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was go to View, and Reset the View.
(Wasted so much time on other things, and in the end it was so simple ...)
Hope this helps others!